# ionic : save data while loading a page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I develop a mobile application using ionic. when I load a page ( using `window.location.reload();` in javascript ) the application lose the information of the user (the information of authentification ) .
I m looking for a solution that allow my app to save these information even I load the page !

I use this service inside my app.js to save the data of the user and share it with controllers

```
.service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var idpersonne,nom,prenom,login,pass,admin ;

        return {
            getIdpersonne: function () {
                return idpersonne;
            },
            setIdpersonne: function(value) {
                idpersonne = value;
            },
             getNom: function () {
                return nom;
            },
            setNom: function(value) {
                nom = value;
            },
             getPrenom: function () {
                return prenom;
            },
            setPrenom: function(value) {
                prenom = value;
            },
             getLogin: function () {
                return login;
            },
            setLogin: function(value) {
                login = value;
            },
             getPass: function () {
                return pass;
            },
            setPass: function(value) {
                pass = value;
            },
             getAdmin: function () {
                return admin;
            },
            setAdmin: function(value) {
                admin = value;
            }
        };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look into the local storage to save data easily (http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/).
This article from Ionic team shows everything in details. 
The basic syntax for the local storage is:

```
window.localStorage['name'] = 'Max';
```

and load the value by:

```
var name = window.localStorage['name'] || 'you';
```

Comment: yes , you're right ! that's exactly what I m looking for .. thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Glad to see the answer was helpful. Cheers!